# Insert rows using liquibase in yaml format

Tags: java, yaml, liquibase

I am trying to define a changeSet to insert two rows in a table using liquibase. In order to do this, I wrote the following changeSet:

```
- changeSet:
  id: 1.0/7
  author: stivlo
  changes:
    -insert:
        tableName: my_table
        columns:
        - column:
            name: id
            value: "1"
        - column:
            name: name
            value: "One"
    -insert:
        tableName: my_table
        columns:
        - column:
            name: id
            value: "2"
        - column:
            name: name
            value: "Two"
```

When I start my Spring Boot application, the changeset is executed, but the rows are not inserted.

In DATABASECHANGELOG table I find a raw saying that the migration was executed, but the description is "Empty", as to signify that liquibase could not see any changes in the migration.

How do I fix my yaml in order to be able to insert those two rows?

---

P.S. I've managed to solve my problem embedding SQL statements instead of using a liquibase insert.

```
- changeSet:
  id: 1.0/7
  author: stivlo
  changes:
    - sql:
        sql: insert into my_table (id, name) values (1, "One")
    - sql:
        sql: insert into my_table (id, name) values (2, "Two")
```

This works, but I am still interested to know how to properly define a liquibase insert. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I've struggled with the same issue and i want to share some thoughts.
First of all, about your particular issue - i think you had a bit malformed .yml, though it may be just stackoverflow formatting. It should look like this:

```
- changeSet:
    id: 1.0/7
    author: stivlo
    comment: "Some comments go here"
    changes:
     - insert:
         tableName: my_table
         columns:
         - column:
             name: id
             value: "1"
         - column:
             name: name
             value: "One"
     - insert:
         tableName: my_table
         columns:
         - column:
             name: id
             value: "2"
         - column:
             name: name
             value: "Two"
```

Please notice that whole changeset content is indented from the beginning of the `- changeSet` block
Also all `-` marks should be followed by whitespaces, otherwise you either see nothing or error in some cases
Btw i hope you didn't forget `databaseChangeLog` block on top of the file?

**Something about troubleshooting liquibase issues:**

(Credit to [this post](https://hahamo.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/running-liquibase-change-sets-part-1-command-line/))

First, as [Mattias B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5856202/mattias-b) mentioned, there is truly helpful "updateSQL" option. I used [CLI](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html),

```
  java -jar liquibase.jar --driver=org.h2.Driver --classpath=h2-1.3.170.jar --changeLogFile=yourchangelogpath/changelog.yaml --url=jdbc:h2:D:/Variaciok/db/variation --username=sa --password= updateSQL
```

You can move almost all options to file, like

```
driver: org.h2.Driver
classpath: h2-1.3.170.jar
changeLogFile: yourchangelogpath/changelog.yaml
url: jdbc:h2:D:/db/variation
username: sa
password:
```

so your command looks like

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --defaultsFile=our_database.properties updateSQL
```

or if you named file `liquibase.properties` you can even skip --defaultsFile so it is just

```
java -jar liquibase.jar updateSQL
```

Second, if you are not seeing any errors either in your runner or in CLI, the problem is almost certainly in malformed .yml

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know its a old post but other people might find this usefull

I would suggest using liquibase "updateSQL" in order to track down the issue by showing the generated SQL.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I think user does not have enough mod points to make comments